# How to get a specific layout in databound list control

Tags: c#, layout, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I want to layout my items in a Windows Phone 8.1 app, not silverlight, in the following order:

[image]

I did some research and tried different panels, but I can't find the right ones :[
I could use a grid and achive that design, BUT I want to add items over a binding and then I would have to change the grid somehow :/

xaml Layout

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <uc:Test/>
</Page.DataContext>

<ScrollViewer>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding t}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="Aqua"
                        BorderThickness="3"
                    Width="100" Height="100">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

test.cs

```
public class Test
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> t { get; set; }
    public Test()
    {
        t = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        t.Add("a");
        t.Add("b");
        t.Add("c");
        t.Add("d");
        t.Add("e");
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

ALSO, I did write a wrong information in the comment below, sorry.
Every Item has the same width, so count and width, will/would give me the position in column and row.

Implementation of PrepareContainerForItemOverride so far:

```
public class ExtendedItemsControl : ItemsControl
{
    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);

        var grid = element as ContentPresenter;
        var count = 0; // <- Count of Items in the Grid
        var width = 0; // <- width of the current Element

        //if (count * width / grid.ActualWidth > 1)
        //    grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());

        Grid.SetRow(grid, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you just want a `WrapPanel`? The order seems nonsensical for an `ItemsControl` otherwise. Could you provide the logic behind the layout?

Comment: After your update, @BradleyDotNET's comment seems prescient to me ... why not just use a WrapPanel as the ItemsPanel?  That should handle the layout for you ...

Comment: I can't find a control named `WrapPanel` do I need any nuget imports for that to work on wp8.1 ?

Comment: Ok got it, you can use the `WrapGrid` Control if you set `Orientation="Horizontal"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Grid along with an `ItemsControl` to achieve the ItemsSource binding:

- First, set the Grid as the ItemsControl's `ItemsPanel`
- Second, subclass the ItemsControl to set the appropriate `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` properties on its children

For the first part (it looks from the picture like you have 4 columns and 3 rows):

```
<local:ExtendedItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <local:ExtendedItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </local:ExtendedItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</local:ExtendedItemsControl>
```

For the second part, I suggest overriding `OnItemsChanged`, and setting the Grid attached properties on each item container as needed.  You could do this by using the implicit sequence of the items:

```
public class ExtendedItemsControl : ItemsControl
{
    protected override void OnItemsChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnItemsChanged(e);

        var item2 = this.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(e.NewItems[1]);
        Grid.SetColumn(item2, 1);

        var item3 = this.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(e.NewItems[2]);
        Grid.SetColumn(item3, 2);
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(item3, 2);

        var item4 = this.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(e.NewItems[3]);
        Grid.SetRow(item4, 1);

        // etc ...
    }
}
```

The above assumes that your source collection doesn't not change once bound -- if it does change, you might consider overriding `PrepareContainerForItemOverride` instead, and setting its Grid Row/Column properties with reference to a property on the item model ("ItemIndex" or whatever):

```
protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
{
    base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
    var contentPresenter = (ContentPresenter)element;
    var itemModel = (MyItemModel)item;
    switch (itemModel.ItemIndex)
    {
        case 1:
            Grid.SetColumn(contentPresenter, 1);
            break;
        case 2:
            Grid.SetColumn(contentPresenter, 2);
            Grid.SetColumnSpan(contentPresenter, 2);
            break;
        // etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry forget to mention that it would change :/
Very usefull answer though, I will try to override the methode you mentioned.

Comment: @MichaM. ah, I guessed wrong ... it seemed counter-intuitive that you would have fixed Grid positions (?) but changing items.  Updated with the second example.

Comment: Is there a way to get the actual grid, within this method ?

Comment: Also my itemModel isn't aware of it's position.
And I would like to handle that in the method above, any way to get my grid?

Comment: @MichaM. getting the ItemsPanel is possible, but painful (have to navigate the visual tree, if I recall).  Can't you set the position using attached properties, based on the item model's index in the ItemsSource?

Comment: My idea would be to get the width of the grid, the width of the element (which can be variable 100, 200, 300 ...) and the count of elements and then determain the row and col.

Comment: Or I think it might be enough if I only get the current amount of elements in the grid, there is no member, at least i didn't spot any, on `ControlPresenter element` which gives me the total count.
I will go to bed now, almost 2 o'clock here, I will get back to this tomorrow.
Also I will update my answer before I turn off the PC ;)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a standard control that will give you the layout you want for arbitrary numbers of different sized items without some custom placement code, but you can customize controls depending on what exactly you need.

Mark Rideout created a customized GridView sample for Windows Store 8.0 at [How To: Create a Variable Sized Grouped GridView (like the store)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/966aa897-1413-46f0-bef7-663de36f9423/how-to-create-a-variable-sized-grouped-gridview-like-the-store?forum=winappswithcsharp) and the techniques you'll use for a Windows Phone Runtime app will be essentially the same. In his control he overrode the [PrepareContainerForItemOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.preparecontainerforitemoverride.aspx) function to look at the individual data items to see if they should be small, medium, or large sized, and then set their columns and spans appropriately in a [VariableSizedWrapGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.variablesizedwrapgrid.aspx).

If you want the exact positioning you show (rather than lining things up) and want to limit to 7 then you could set the ItemsPanel to a Grid instead of the VariableSizedWrapGrid and set the items into specific rows and columns in the same way.